# Open a pdf with default windows behaviour from a WPF application

Tags: wpf, pdf, process

I want to open a PDF with the default windows behaviour the user has saved (e.g. internet explorer, adobe, whatever).

I found this solution
[Opening a .pdf file in windows form through a button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36721387/opening-a-pdf-file-in-windows-form-through-a-button-click)

and implemented it here:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("MyPdfPath");
        Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Sadly I got an Error:

```
   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."
```

I tried to google this error, but nothing of the first ten solution ideas worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system is treating it like an executable, one way to get the document behavior is to set [UseShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=net-5.0) to true:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("MyPdfPath");
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808315/net-core-2-0-process-start-throws-the-specified-executable-is-not-a-valid-appl/47066203#47066203 the link to which appears in the linked question.